# How to find the best prior art?

Tags: discussion, tools

Where's the best place to look to find prior art? Obviously you can [search old patents](https://www.google.com/?tbm=pts&hl=en) and [The Internet Archive](http://www.archive.org/) is extremely helpful. Are there any other places that are best suited for finding really good prior art?

Comment: Is there a particular technical field you're interested in? The "best place to look" depends on the field of prior art you want to search.

Answer (score 3):

You may use libraries, books, presentations, magazines, videos, thesis, research papers, trade fair publications, etc etc. This list is endless. Depends on technology fields.

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest the Google Book Search - it does turn up obscure titles which otherwise may not be available for research, especially out-of-print books and they even have some magazine archives.